# UIAccessibility notifications not being posted by UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, uiaccessibility

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(closedCaptioningStatusChanged(_:)), name: .UIAccessibilityClosedCaptioningStatusDidChange, object: nil)
}

@objc func closedCaptioningStatusChanged(_ notif: NSNotification) {
    print("closedCaptioningStatusChanged")
}
```

I tried changing CC settings in accessibilities and in the default video player. Any ideas why `closedCaptioningStatusChanged` is not called?

**EDIT:**

Notifications for all `UIAccessibility` settings are not called for some reason. Is there something I'm not doing?

**EDIT 2:**

I ran on both simulator and device (Apple TV). I tried changing the CC settings in accessibility and AVPlayer, but neither of them triggered the notification.

Comment: Are you using a device ? Is accessibility turned on the device ?

Comment: There doesn't seem anything wrong with your code. It worked for me with real device as well as simulator. So can you please explain the steps you're following for testing this particular scenario?

Comment: In what class is this implemented? Are you sure that your addObserver code is called?

Comment: @KeyurTailor I tried both on device and simulator

Comment: @MendyK That's great. So can you explain exactly how you're testing this scenario? Based on that, may be I can suggest something.